# Buttons not working on ipad simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I've recently updated my project for iOS 10 and now the buttons on the bottom of the screen don't work in the ipad simulator. Other buttons in the app work while in the ipad simulator and all of the buttons work on all of the other simulators. Tried searching around for this problem but didn't find anything so I'm pretty stumped.

Edit:
Buttons that aren't working are "Bet High", "+", "-", "Bet Low". You can click them and tell they are clicked by the animation but the action linked to the buttons aren't getting called. Clicking the ad works too

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mOQ9.png)

Edit #2: 
Now I feel stupid. After poking around with NSLog I found that the iPad Pro (9.7 inch) simulator thought it was a 3.5 inch display so it was using my storyboard for 3.5 inch displays which didn't have those buttons hooked up to their corresponding actions (still weird though as each storyboard was duplicated from my original storyboard for the 4.7 inch display which had everything hooked up when duplicated)
*face palm

Comment: As you stated above that you have a button at the bottom so is it in a toolbar? Have you check your view hierarchy for the view in iPad designing view?
If possible can you please specify more about your issue? Like Screenshot showing your button location, code for the action event of the particular button, view hierarchy of your screen for iPad, etc.

Comment: For this kind of scenario it is highly possible that your button may goes under another controller which cover the touch area of the button. I recommend to check your view hierarchy first.

Comment: Already check the hierarchy and moved views around in the hieraarchy but still nothing

Comment: Have you checked your IBOutlets properly?? Check if any other view is not suppressing these buttons .

Comment: Are you using scrollview as parent view for this buttons?

Comment: @VishalSonawane Yes, I've checked the IBOutlets. Have tried deleting the buttons completely and relinking to a new action but still nothing. Button is the top most view and you can tell the button recognizes a tap because of the animation when clicked yet the action is still not called

Comment: @DipankarDas No, the button is inside of a UIView

Answer (score -1):

Check the UI like storyboard, buttons and so on. You can try rebuild the button again. If the problem still happen again, copy the sample code from internet like Apple Developer and check your code. You can also the your  simulator and run it again.

Comment: Please try to provide appropriate links or code snippet  in your answer. Every developer knows how to copy paste the code. :)